# How to convert from String to a primitive type or standard java Wrapper types

Tags: java, string, object, reflection, type-conversion

I have a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler` and I need to implement the method invoke()

I have a value of type `java.lang.String` from my elaboration and I need to convert this value to the appropriate returnType expected by the method (it can be a primitive like int, boolean, double or wrapper classes like Boolean, Integer, Double, Float, etc).

Example:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) 
        throws Throwable {
    String computedValue = compute(...);
    return convert(method.getReturnType(), computedValue);
}

private Object convert(Class<?> returnType, String stringValue) {
    return ...; // what's the simplest way?
}
```

I am not expecting to simply implement an automatic conversion between complex objects, but I expect a simple way to convert from String to the standard java types.

I've seen (too) many times stuff like this, but it doesn't seem appropriate to me:

```
public static Object toObject( Class clazz, String value ) {
    if( Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Boolean.parseBoolean( value );
    if( Byte.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Byte.parseByte( value );
    if( Short.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Short.parseShort( value );
    if( Integer.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Integer.parseInteger( value );
    if( Long.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Long.parseLong( value );
    if( Float.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Float.parseFloat( value );
    if( Double.class.isAssignableFrom( clazz ) ) return Double.parseDouble( value );
    return value;
}
```

and the above is not even the worse one I saw, so far :)

Does anybody have a secret trick here?

Comment: Tell us: 1. Why your first example isn't working, and 2. What "doesn't seem appropriate" means.

Comment: 1. the first example doesn't work because in the convert method it is missing the implementation (which is the subject topic for this question)
2. doesn't seems appropriate means that in my opinion this implementation is pretty ugly due to the many ifs, and I suppose there is a better way to do this job.

Comment: Since the second example *works* (but it's just ugly), http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better option.

Comment: Thanks @luiscubal, it's true, it works, but I don't want ugly stuff in my codebase; I cannot watch it :)

Comment: I would hope that the native method isAssignableFrom() does a == check as first operation, so the improvement you proposed should not make a big difference. Thanks for your hint. I would rather make ugly code to look worse by purpose, as memento to replace it later (kidding again).

Comment: It is not 'Integer.parseInteger()' it is 'Integer.parseInt()'. I have updated the answer with this correction.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no real alternative to the version you presented.  You can simplify it a bit (since the wrapper types are all `final`), but you essentially need to use `if` or `switch` or hashing to switch on the class.

My advice is to code it like the above.  Ugly code is only a problem *per se* if you have to look at it.  So put it inside a utility method and don't look at it again.

---

FWIW - this is how I'd simplify the method:

```
public static Object toObject( Class clazz, String value ) {
    if( Boolean.class == clazz ) return Boolean.parseBoolean( value );
    if( Byte.class == clazz ) return Byte.parseByte( value );
    if( Short.class == clazz ) return Short.parseShort( value );
    if( Integer.class == clazz ) return Integer.parseInt( value );
    if( Long.class == clazz ) return Long.parseLong( value );
    if( Float.class == clazz ) return Float.parseFloat( value );
    if( Double.class == clazz ) return Double.parseDouble( value );
    return value;
}
```

This is simpler and more efficient.  And it is equivalent to the original version because  the classes are all `final` and because the specs state that equality for `Class` objects is object identity.

Arguably, we should be using the `<wrapper>.valueOf(String)` methods which return the wrapper objects directly.

I make no claim that this is less ugly ... but "beauty" is not a useful measure of code quality, because it is subjective and because it doesn't tell you whether the code is easy to understand and / or maintain.

**UPDATE**

To support primitive types as well, add the corresponding classes to the `if` conditions; e.g.

```
    if (Boolean.class == clazz || Boolean.TYPE == clazz) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
    }
```

It may now be getting to the point where doing a String switch on the type's name is more efficient, though there are some slightly knotty issues of type identity that need to be thought through.  (In theory, you can have multiple types with the same full name that have been loaded by different classloaders.  I think you'd need to "play fast and loose" in a classloader to do that with the primitive wrapper classes ... but I think it might still be possible.)

Answer (score 26):

I think I found something

```
import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorManager;

@Override
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    String returnValue = ...
    return convert(method.getReturnType(), returnValue); 
}

private Object convert(Class<?> targetType, String text) {
    PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(targetType);
    editor.setAsText(text);
    return editor.getValue();
}
```

I think that those 3 lines of code are better than the multiple ifs, and I avoided to add external library dependencies, since `java.beans` package is inside the Java standard libraries (javadocs: [`PropertyEditorManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditorManager.html)).

I find it quite acceptable; my only perplexity is that `PropertyEditor` is contained in `java.beans` package and I would have preferred something available in `java.util` or `java.lang.reflect` package, since this code has nothing to do with `java.beans` actually.

The code above has also the advantage that you can register additional `PropertyEditor` instances to translate complex objects, btw. That's not a bad thing to have though.

I think it's better than a list of ifs, in beauty, but also in quality.

Comment: I think it's the only one working ALSO with primitive types. But it doesn't work on android:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988376/missing-runtime-dependencies-with-owner-gradle-for-android

Answer (score 8):

Probably [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/index.html) can help?

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils;
// ...
final Object v = ConvertUtils.convert("42", Integer.class);
```

Comment: I tested it, it returns 0 when it fails to parse the string `test` to `Long` that's not good as I need to distinguish between succeeded  and failed converts

Comment: This is really bad as it doesn't throw an exception in the case of spam data.

Comment: The `Integer.parseInt("12")` is a lot better as it will throw RunTimeException and you will know what is the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I propose this:

```
List<Class<?>> clsList = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
clsList.add(Boolean.class);
clsList.add(Integer.class);
//etc.

for (Class<?> cls : clsList) {
    if (cls.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
        return cls.getMethod("valueOf", new Class[] { String.class }).invoke(null, new Object[] { value });
        //Missing in this example: Handle a few exceptions
    }
}
```

I'll leave it to you whether this looks cleaner or uglier.

Comment: Another option I can think to avoid reflection, would be to create a Map<Class<?>,Converter> to avoid reflection. Converter interface could have a single method `Object convert(String)`, then mapping Boolean.class to BooleanConverter; Integer.class to IntegerConverter and so on... at least, this won't be so ugly as multiple ifs.

Comment: This doesn't work with primitive types: int.class.getMethod("valueOf", new Class[]{String.class}) throws NoSuchMethodException

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano - It should be pointed out that the code you are trying to replace doesn't work with primitives either.

Comment: THIS is the good one. But why iterating over hardcoded types?? That is precisely what it solves. Why not simpler `return returnType.getMethod("valueOf",String.class).invoke(null, stringValue);`
It actually works with all the basic types you enumerated. Not with Atomic*.class classes, and some exceptions (Some are supported if you change valueO fby the constructor(String) through reflection, like BigInteger);

Answer (score 5):

There is a lightweight library that parses strings to  java types which does what you want. It's called type-parser and you can find it on github [here](https://github.com/drapostolos/type-parser/wiki/User-Guide).

Your above code could then look something like this:

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
    TypeParser parser = TypeParser.newBuilder().build();
    String computedValue = compute(...);
    return parser.parseType(computedValue,  method.getGenericReturnType());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in jdk8, you could now do something like so O(1) lookup time with no if statements...

A better version now that handles nulls correct is here

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/webserver/http-router/src/main/java/org/webpieces/router/impl/params/ObjectTranslator.java

```
private Map<Class<?>, Function<String, Object>> classToUnmarshaller = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, String>> classToMarshaller = new HashMap<>();

public ObjectTranslator() {
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Boolean.class, s -> s == null ? null : Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Boolean.TYPE, s -> Boolean.parseBoolean(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Byte.class, s -> s == null ? null : Byte.parseByte(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Byte.TYPE, s -> Byte.parseByte(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Short.class, s -> s == null ? null : Short.parseShort(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Short.TYPE, s -> Short.parseShort(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Integer.class, s -> s == null ? null : Integer.parseInt(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Integer.TYPE, s -> Integer.parseInt(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Long.class, s -> s == null ? null : Long.parseLong(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Long.TYPE, s -> Long.parseLong(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Float.class, s -> s == null ? null : Float.parseFloat(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Float.TYPE, s -> Float.parseFloat(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Double.class, s -> s == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(Double.TYPE, s -> Double.parseDouble(s));
    classToUnmarshaller.put(String.class, s -> s);

    classToMarshaller.put(Boolean.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Boolean.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Byte.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Byte.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Short.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Short.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Integer.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Integer.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Long.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Long.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Float.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Float.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Double.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(Double.TYPE, s -> s.toString());
    classToMarshaller.put(String.class, s -> s == null ? null : s.toString());
}

public Function<String, Object> getUnmarshaller(Class<?> paramTypeToCreate) {
    return classToUnmarshaller.get(paramTypeToCreate);
}

public Function<Object, String> getMarshaller(Class<?> type) {
    return classToMarshaller.get(type);
}
```

such that you can then call

```
primitiveTranslator.getConverter(Integer.TYPE).apply(stringToConvert);
```