# Is there any lightweight java open source library that converts a String to a type?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have made a few libraries that internally reads a value from a file (xml/properties etc) and converts it to some type. For example convert "5" to an integer, or "AAA" to an enum (assuming there is a matching enum available) etc. Similar as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943550/how-to-convert-from-string-to-a-primitive-type-or-standard-java-wrapper-types) question.

Instead of copy/paste the same code every where I'm wondering if there is a open source library that I can use that does just this? Preferable something light weight, as I don't want to bring in a 1MB sized library just for this. I would be fine with a library that only do just this. With an API looking something like this:

```
Integer myInteger = StringConverter.toType(Integer.class, "5");
MyEnum myEnum = StringConverter.toType(MyEnum.class, "AAA");
boolean myBool = StringConverter-toType(boolean.class, "true");
```

I have been looking around but could not find one. If there is no one, I'll go ahead and create one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `String.valueOf` and/or `Integer.parseInt` et al.